# Why does "confine" have a "negative" meaning with a "con" prefix?

Tags: meaning

I am puzzled about the reason why "confine" means "restrict; place limits on".

My doubts are:(1)"con-" prefix has a uasge of "intensify their meaning" (refer in [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/con-)); (2) "fine" means "good". Why the combination of them leads to "not good" instead of "goooood" in order to intensify the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The etymology of a word does not strictly dictate its meaning, but in this case, it would have been useful to look up the etymology of *confine* itself. The word is not formed in English, but rather, as Oxford Living Dictionaries has it, *[confine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confine)* derives

> from French *confins* (plural noun), from Latin *confinia*, from *confinis* ‘bordering’, from *con-* ‘together’ + *finis* ‘end, limit’ (plural *fines* ‘territory’). The verb senses are from French *confiner*, based on Latin *confinis*.

The Latin word, in other words, is akin to *with a boundary*, not *intensely good* as you propose. The verb meaning naturally follows to circumscribe, and metaphorically to set a bounding limit.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the prefix con- refers to its other meaning, "with." Furthermore, the second syllable of the word, "fine," does not refer to the English word "fine," but instead, the Latin word finis, meaning "end" or "boundary." Combining the two, you have a literal translation of "with boundaries." This definition is in line with that which you provided for the verb form of "confine," and also the definition, "something that encloses," of the noun form.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig around in the dictionary a bit, you'll find that there's a prefix [com-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/com-) that means "with" or "together", as seen in words like "companion" or "comrade".  Furthermore, before certain consonants, that prefix modifies to [con-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/con-).  Other words using this "con-" prefix to mean "together" include "contiguous" and "connection".

Answer (score 1):

Although the two words do trace their roots back to the same vocable of Latin origin, in Modern English, ***fine*** in the verb ***confine*** has literally nothing to do with the adjective ***fine*** which means *good* or *of very high quality*. And of course that explains why they mean different things. In other words, ***fine*** in ***confine*** is not the ***fine*** you're thinking of. ***confine*** originally entered English through French in the form of the verb ***confiner*** which meant *to have a common boundary* or *to share a limit* (*con* means together and *finer* means *to limit*). **fine**, on the other hand, came from a separate word. Here's what Wiktionary has to say about [**its etymology**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fine#Etymology_1):

> From Middle English fin, fyn, from Old French fin (“fine, minute, exact”), probably from Latin finitus (“literally finished (used as an adjective by Cicero, of words, well rounded)”), past participle of fīnīre (“to limit, bound, define, terminate, finish”), from finis (“a limit, end”).